# Do you need two separate IPs each, for hosting a website, and for hosting a mail server? [IPv4]

Tags: ip-address, isp, ipv4, static-ip

Edit - I am only talking about public static IP addresses here.

Do you need two separate IP addresses each, for hosting a website, and for hosting a mail server? Or can I use the same IP address for both the things. I have seen many mail servers use two IP addresses each, for mail and web services. Is it mandatory? What will be the consequences for having one IP address, or for having two IP addresses?

And if it is mandatory to use two separate IP addresses, can one ISP provide two static IP addresses through the same cable with PPPoe IPv4? Or do I need separate connections for each of the IP addresses?

Just in case.... I am not using a business line. Just a normal broadband for home. I already have one Static IP address.

If I do get two static ips anyway, can I get them through the same PPPoe connection (one cable)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Do you need two separate IPs for hosting a website and a mail server?

No, because typically SMTP, POP, HTTP, HTTPS etc. run on different ports:

```
Port  25  SMTP
Port  80 HTTP
Port 110 POP
Port 443 HTTPS
Port 143 IMAP
Port 465 SMTPS
Port 587 SMA
Port 993 IMAPS
Port 995 POPS
```